# about the UIActivityIndicatorView in iOS

Tags: ios

Assume that there's a `UIView` as a container, which contain an `UIActivityIndicatorView` and other subviews.When the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is animating, it set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO, which makes all it's sibling views stop receiving input events.

I checkout the doc of Apple, it suggest we can use the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` constant to resolve this problem.But I dont know where or which property to set this constant.Has anyone encountered this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` is one of options for animating views with blocks. Allow the user to interact with views while they are being animated.

```
enum {
   UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews            = 1 <<  0,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = 1 <<  1,
   UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState     = 1 <<  2,
   UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat                    = 1 <<  3,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse               = 1 <<  4,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration = 1 <<  5,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve    = 1 <<  6,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent      = 1 <<  7,
   UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews   = 1 <<  8,

   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   = 5 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     = 6 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  = 7 << 20,
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAnimationOptions;
```

But I don't know how it may help you for using UIActivityIndicatorView. Simple example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f 
                      delay:0.2f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [myView setFrame:CGRectOffset(view.frame, 0, -100)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                         NSLog(@"completed");
                     }
 ];
```

Comment: When using `UIActivityIndicatorView` I usually create empty holder view, bring it to front and put into it UIActivityIndicatorView. When process will be finished just delete this view